# Фильтр блоков на чистом JS

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код, который фильтрует блоки по выбранному цвету:

```js
var filter_button_el = document.getElementById('filter');
var items_el = document.getElementById('items');

filter_button_el.onclick = function() {
  console.log(this.value);
  var items = items_el.getElementsByClassName('item');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].classList.contains(this.value)) {
      items[i].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      items[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}

var filter_select_el = document.getElementById('filter1');
var items_el = document.getElementById('items');

filter_select_el.onclick = function() {
  console.log(this.value);
  var items = items_el.getElementsByClassName('item');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].classList.contains(this.value)) {
      items[i].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      items[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#items {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.item {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.red {
  background: #cf2624;
}

.blue {
  background: #2478cf;
}

.green {
  background: #24cf7c;
}

.orange {
  background: #cf7c24;
}

.yellow {
  background: #f1e81f;
}
```

```html
<select id="filter1">
  <option value="">Сбросить</option>
  <option value="item">все</option>
  <option value="red">красный</option>
  <option value="blue">синий</option>
  <option value="green">зелёный</option>
  <option value="orange">оранжевый</option>
  <option value="yellow">жёлтый</option>
</select>

<button id="filter" value="red">Красный</button>

<div id="items">
  <div class="item red">1</div>
  <div class="item blue">2</div>
  <div class="item red">3</div>
  <div class="item green">4</div>
  <div class="item red">5</div>
  <div class="item orange">6</div>
  <div class="item green">7</div>
  <div class="item yellow">8</div>
  <div class="item green">9</div>
  <div class="item orange">10</div>
  <div class="item yellow">11</div>
  <div class="item blue">12</div>
  <div class="item green">13</div>
  <div class="item orange">14</div>
  <div class="item blue">15</div>
  <div class="item orange">16</div>
  <div class="item red">17</div>
  <div class="item yellow">18</div>
</div>
```

По отдельности всё работает (список фильтрует, кнопка то же).

Не понимаю как сделать фильтр вроде чекбоксов. То есть, при выборе в списке "Синий" - остаются все синие блоки, при нажатии на кнопку "Красный" - добавляются красные блоки.
Нужно, что бы принцип работы был следующий: список воспринимался - чекбоксом, а кнопки - "радио".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

( [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/sek0g4cx/) )

```js
var radio = document.getElementById('radio'); // селект - псевдорадио
var check = document.querySelectorAll('.check'); // кнопки - псевдочекбоксы
var items = document.getElementById('items'); // цветные квадратики

radio.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var val = this.value;
  var item = items.querySelectorAll('.item');
  for ( var i = 0; i < item.length; i++ ) {
    if (item[i].classList.contains( val )) {
      item[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      item[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  for( i = 0; i < check.length; i++ ){
    var ch = check[i];
    if( ch.value === val || this.value === "item" ){
      ch.classList.add('checked'); // Класс-индикатор отмеченности
      ch.chosen = true;
    } else {    
      ch.classList.remove('checked');
      ch.chosen = false;
    }
  }
});

for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
  check[i].chosen = true; // Изначально все показаны
  check[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.chosen = !this.chosen; // Значение переключается, как у обычных чекбоксов
    this.classList.toggle('checked');
    var item = items.querySelectorAll('.' + this.value); 
    for( var u = 0; u < item.length; u++ ){
      item[u].style.display = this.chosen ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#items {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.item {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.red {
  background: #cf2624;
}

.blue {
  background: #2478cf;
}

.green {
  background: #24cf7c;
}

.orange {
  background: #cf7c24;
}

.yellow {
  background: #f1e81f;
}

.check::before {
  content: "• ";
  color: #999;
}
.checked::before {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select id="radio">
  <option value="">Сбросить</option>
  <option value="item">все</option>
  <option value="red">красный</option>
  <option value="blue">синий</option>
  <option value="green">зелёный</option>
  <option value="orange">оранжевый</option>
  <option value="yellow">жёлтый</option>
</select>

<button class="check checked" value="red">Красный</button>
<button class="check checked" value="green">Зеленый</button>

<div id="items">
  <div class="item red">1</div>
  <div class="item blue">2</div>
  <div class="item red">3</div>
  <div class="item green">4</div>
  <div class="item red">5</div>
  <div class="item orange">6</div>
  <div class="item green">7</div>
  <div class="item yellow">8</div>
  <div class="item green">9</div>
  <div class="item orange">10</div>
  <div class="item yellow">11</div>
  <div class="item blue">12</div>
  <div class="item green">13</div>
  <div class="item orange">14</div>
  <div class="item blue">15</div>
  <div class="item orange">16</div>
  <div class="item red">17</div>
  <div class="item yellow">18</div>
</div>
```

P.s. `float-left` надо бы заменить на `display: inline-block;` А образовавшиеся пробелы можно убрать, если удалить пробелы между элементами, так:

```
<div> ... </div
><div> ... </div
><div> ... </div>
```